# Hey.iam working on a react project .iam using scrolltrigger in my project.it id woking when i run it locally. but not working after hosted infirebase

Tags: reactjs, scrolltrigger

[**[enter image description here](https://disneyclone-16df0.web.app/home/main)**][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/943Rp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your screenshot , maybe you need to use **scrollTrigger** , NOT **ScrollTrigger**

Comment: i have used scrollTrigger only.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).